# Page keep redirecting back to the same page while it should be redirect to another page with data in Laravel Project

Tags: laravel

I have a method that should collect test answers (Yes or No) from the form, calculate the results, and insert them into the Database Table. But once the user clicks on submit, it will redirect back to the same question page. Below is the code:

```
 public function storeAnswer(Request $request, $id) {

        $questions = Question::with('category')->get();

        if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
            $answers = $request->input('answer');

            //$request->dd();

            $passCountByCategory = [];

            foreach ($questions as $question) {
                $answer = $answers[$question->id] ?? null;

                if ($answer === 'Yes') {
                    $categoryId = $question->category->id;
                    $passCountByCategory[$categoryId] = ($passCountByCategory[$categoryId] ?? 0) + 1;
                } elseif ($answer === 'No') {
                    $categoryId = $question->category->id;
                    $passCountByCategory[$categoryId] = ($passCountByCategory[$categoryId] ?? 0);

                } else {

                    return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'You did not choose any options');
                }
            }

            $overallPassed = 0;
            $overallTotal = 0;

            foreach ($passCountByCategory as $categoryId => $passCount) {
                $category = Category::find($categoryId);
                $categoryTotal = count($category->questions);
                $categoryPassed = $passCount;

                $categoryResult = new CategoryResult();
                $categoryResult->result_id      = $id;
                $categoryResult->category_name  = $category->name;
                $categoryResult->pass_count     = $categoryPassed;
                $categoryResult->total_count    = $categoryTotal;
                $categoryResult->percentage     = ($categoryPassed / $categoryTotal) * 100;
                $categoryResult->category_status = ($categoryPassed >= 2) ? 'Passed' : 'Failed';
                $categoryResult->save();

                $overallPassed += $categoryPassed;
                $overallTotal += $categoryTotal;
            }

            $overallPercentage = ($overallPassed / $overallTotal) * 100;
            $overallStatus = ($overallPercentage >= 66) ? 'Passed' : 'Failed';

            $testResult = new TestResults();
            $testResult->app_id         = $id;
            $testResult->pass_count     = $overallPassed;
            $testResult->total_count    = $overallTotal;
            $testResult->percentage     = $overallPercentage;
            $testResult->status         = $overallStatus;
            $testResult->save();

            $app_name = UserApps::where('app_id', $id)->value('app_name');

            $appStatus = ($overallStatus === 'Passed') ? 'Certified' : 'Unapproved';
            UserApps::where('app_id', $id)->update(['status' => $appStatus]);

            return redirect()->route('test.results', ['id' => $id]);
        }

    }
```

What could have been the issue?

Apparently, this is the getResults method:

```
public function getResults($id) {

        $testResult = TestResults::findOrFail($id);
        $categoryResults = CategoryResult::where('result_id', $id)->get();

        return view('result_view', compact('testResult', 'categoryResults'));

    }
```

Here are my two routes:

```
Route::post('/user/store-results/{id}', [QuestionController::class, 'storeAnswer'])->name('store_results');

Route::get('/user/results-test/{id}', [QuestionController::class, 'getResults'])->name('test.results');
```

I could not figure out what could be the problem.